# The Fubini property of the $\sigma$-ideal generated by closed subsets of measure zero

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

**Question.** Can a Borel subset $B\subset\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ be covered by countably many closed sets of measure zero in the plane if for every $(a,b)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ the horisontal and vertical sections $\{x\in \mathbb R:(x,b)\in  B\}$ and $\{y\in\mathbb R:(a,y)\in B\}$ of $B$ can be covered by countable number of closed sets of measure zero in the real line?

Comment: Is it obvious or well-known that your $\sigma$-ideals actually differ from the $\sigma$-ideals of Borel null sets?

Comment: @LutzMattner It is not obvious but well-known that my ideal is strictly smaller than the ideal of meager null sets. The standard counterexample is a dense $G_\delta$-set $G$ of measure zero in a Cantor set of positive measure on the real line. The set $G$ is nowhere dense and has measure zero but by Baire Theorem cannot be covered by a countable family of closed sets of measure zero.

Comment: In fact, I already know how to construct a counterexample to this my problem but have no time to write it down (the construction is a bit long).